# Does SonarQube different version gives different number of issues for same code?

Tags: java, sonarqube, issue-tracking

I have deployed the same code on two different sonar versions with quality profile applied as 'Sonar Way' Java. Still for the same code i am getting different number of issue count and different issue rules applied still i can see that profile is same for both. Can anyone suggest what could be missing ?

### [image: Environment-1]

[image: Environment-2]

There is a line difference probably due to line addition but not created build on the first environment(Please ignore one line difference)

Comment: Would you mind sharing the different version of the sonar-java plugin you are using ?

Comment: Sure , Environment - 1  is of version 5.0.1 and environment-2 is of version 5.1

Comment: Those are version of SonarQube. Not version of sonar-java plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Explication is pretty simple : when a new version of SonarQube is released it ships with the new version of the Sonar-Java Plugin released at the time.

Each release version of the java plugin provides new rules that can be added to the quality profile (so, new issues because of new rules) and also some bug fixes to reduce false positive (that can explain removal of some issues) and false negatives (so new issues for some rules). 
Sonar Way quality profile is evolving with release versions of java plugin.

Comment: :: Thanks for your input,but if the quality profile is applied same so i think same rules are applied for both, still there is a difference, and can you please suggest how to find java-plugin version and changing version if possible.

Comment: Check through update center. Quality profile may be the same but might have been updated with new rules. And even with the same rules, fixing rule might lead to difference in number of issues reported.